# WebTransport Support for getStats API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webtransport

I am using WebTransport(https://w3c.github.io/webtransport/) to implement an application that communicates with the server in QUIC protocol. I planned to make my application control data generating speed with the current network state, so I tried to utilize the getStats API of WebTransport in the chrome browser, but it returns that WebTransport doesn't have getStats function.

My code is like this.

```
var transport = new WebTransport(host);
console.log(transport.getStats());
```

Is there any way to utilize the getStat function with WebTransport?